# How do I get ASP.NET Web API (self-hosted) to listen on *only* localhost?

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm following the example [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=896) for a self-hosted ASP.NET Web API service. However, when specifying "localhost" as the host in the base address, it is translated to "+" (meaning "all available").

```
var baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:13210");
var configuration = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(baseAddress);
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional});

using (var server = new HttpSelfHostServer(configuration))
{
    server.OpenAsync().Wait();
    stop.WaitOne();
    server.CloseAsync().Wait();
}
```

I really do want my host bound to just "localhost" -- it will only be accessed from the same machine, and I don't want to mess around with URL ACLs.

How do I configure Web API to *not* rewrite "localhost" to "+"?

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/api ?

Comment: Nope. That gets rewritten as well.

Comment: as a workaroud while looking into this a bit further what happens if you add a domain (eg me.localhost) to your `hosts` file that maps to 127.0.0.1 and then you get webapi to list on me.localhost/api ?

Comment: Thanks. Just for my knowledge, how (and at which layer) do you find out it's translated to `+`?

Comment: I used JetBrains dotPeek.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set your `HostNameComparisonMode` property to Exact:

```
var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration("https://localhost/api/");
config.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.Exact;
```

See [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163412.aspx) for more information on HostNameComparisonMode

Comment: Thanks. I'd just spent an hour digging around in dotPeek. Even with that information, I still can't find where the transformation actually happens.

Comment: no worries it was actually posted untested but I knew this property existed on the WCF `binding` element so I'm assuming that gets passed down to the endpoint bindings (not sure exactly in what form webapi uses wcf under the hood tho)

Comment: I knew it existed in WCF, but I assumed it controlled validation once a request had arrived, rather than controlling what the listener actually attempted to bind to.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe it does indeed get passed to the binding. see `OnConfigureBinding` in `System.Web.Http.SelfHost.HttpSelfHostConfiguration` line 325